# When is the cohomology of the limit not the limit of the cohomology?

Tags: group-cohomology

Let $G$ be a profinite group, and $A$ a G-module. If $G$ is the projective limit of {$G_{\alpha}$}, and $A$ the direct limit of {$A_{\alpha}$}, then
$H^*(G,A)$ is isomorphic to $dir lim_{\alpha} H^*(G_{\alpha},A_{\alpha})$.
Here the cohomology groups are defined via the group of *continuous* functions from $G$ to $A$. [At page 26 of this book](http://books.google.com.tw/books/about/Profinite_Groups_Arithmetic_and_Geometry.html?id=4db3mlk6kXAC&redir_esc=y) it is asserted that this theorem is false on *discontinuous* cochains. And my question is: is there an example illustrating this statement?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: So you're asking for an example where $H^*_{\text{cont.}}(G,A) \not\cong H^*_{\text{discont.}}(G,A)$?

Comment: Actually I would like to see an example showing that the equality holds not, on discontinuous cochains. Thanks for your attention in any case.

Comment: Dear @awllower, I don't understand the question... What equality? Please be more precise.

Comment: I mean this isomorphism, which I referred to earlier as the equality: $H^*_{\text{cont.}}(G,A) \cong dir limH^*_{\text{cont.}}(G_{\alpha},A_{\alpha})$ That is to say, the "theorem" alludes to that isomorphism exactly.

Answer (score 1):

If you take a prime $p$ and a non-commutative finitely generated free pro-$p$ group $F$, then the second continuous cohomology group with coefficients in $\mathbb Z/p$ is trivial $$H^2_{\sf cont}(F,\mathbb Z/p)  =0$$ but the discrete (discontinuous) cohomology group is uncountable (in particular, it is nontrivial)  $$H^2_{\sf disc}(F,\mathbb Z/p)\ne 0.$$ 
(see [this](https://www.cambridge.org/core/journals/compositio-mathematica/article/on-discrete-homology-of-a-free-pro-p-group/4C72796978A756FB40F6BDD1B1513AA3) or [this](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1705.09131.pdf) ).

Since $$H^2_{\sf cont}(F,\mathbb Z/p)=\varinjlim H^2_{\sf disc}(F/U,\mathbb Z/p)$$ and $F=\varprojlim F/U,$ where $U$ runs over all open normal subgroups, this is a counterexample to your statement.